# Как установить новое значение переменной в запросе с UNION во второй его части

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Есть View (к сожалению не могу показать - громоздкий код и нельзя разглашать)
Вот его часть:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
  SELECT *
  FROM tabl
  WHERE date BETWEEN
  ...
  ORDER BY
    (CASE MyFunction() WHEN 'DESC'  THEN date END) DESC,
    (CASE MyFunction() WHEN 'ASC' THEN date END) ASC
```

Делаю немного странную вещь (об этом еще српошу) - опрашиваю функцию
MyFunction() и по значению меняю сортировку.

Теперь код функции:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction() returns TEXT NO SQL  DETERMINISTIC
return @Val;
```

Тут всего лишь возвращается некая переменная. Детерминированная.

И вот главный запрос с Union и переменными:

```
select * , Min(MyView.date) as `start`, Max(MyView.date) as `end`, sum(MyView.count) as `count`
from (select  @Val := 'ASC') _ ,MyView
left join tabl t on (t.count = MyView.count) and (t.id = MyView.id)
UNION ALL
select *,Min(MyView.date) as `start`, Max(MyView.date) as `end`, sum(MyView.count) as `count`
from (select  @Val := 'DESC') _, MyView
left join tabl t on (t.count = MyView.count) and (t.id = MyView.id)
```

Пояснение:

- Запросы отличаются только направлением сортировки DESC / ASC
- Перед использованием View, во FROM блоке, переменной назначается новое значение (select  @Val := 'ASC')
- если запросы разъединить, направления ORDER BY работают как надо.
- функция нужна для того, что бы хакнуть View, он ведь не может принимать параметры (см хак тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/5331792/5474389)
- база - MariaDB

Не работает часть

> from (select  @Val := 'ASC')

в первом запросе. ASC не проходит во View.
В результате получается 2 одинаковых запроса, как если бы передается все время 'DESC'

Что пробовал:

1. использовать  select SQL_NO_CACHE...
   Пишет : Incorrect usage/placement of 'SQL_NO_CACHE'
2. там по ссылке в комменте предлагали решение:
   "Необходимо установить @p1 := NULL; в виде отдельного оператора. Или начать новый сеанс, в котором переменная еще не определена."
   как-то не помогло.

Вопросы:

1. как все таки в UNION запросе для каждой его части передать разные значения переменной?
2. Вобще такая схема , чтобы убрать дублирование большого запроса, его вынес в View. Разумно ли так делать, или в SQL лучше не мудрить и прописывать 2 похожих View?

Comment: *И вот главный запрос с Union и переменными* Достаточно. Нелинейный запрос - значит, с UDV будет твориться непонятная фигня. Самое простое решение: 1) использование двух разных переменных; 2) перемещение обращения к функции в подзапрос.

Comment: какая у вас версия MySQL то? а то мб 8, и есть CTE, а вьюха создана ради одного случая. Сортировка там с лимитом, надо полагать, типа N-первых, N-последних. того глядишь, row_number решит все без лишних проблем

Comment: там кстати можно напиать без двойной сортировки с минусом `order by case .. when ... then d else -d end`, или есть функция вернет +/- 1, то `func()*d`. Там правда наверное конвертация неявная будет к timestamp, поэтому индекс для сортировки пойдет мимо

Comment: С другой стороны дата-время нативно должно храниться в виде флоата, так что мб и допустимо

Comment: сортировку и лимит вообще проще убрать из вьюхи и написать ее непосредственно в запросе. Если это более нигде не используется